# How to correctly write an expression in a v-bind?

Tags: vue.js

I want to write a v-bind with a condition

```
v-bind:data-sorted="{{sorted ? '1': '0'}}"
```

but, an error occurs

```
invalid expression: expected property name, got '{' in

    {{sorted ? '1': '0'}}

  Raw expression: v-bind:data-sorted="{{sorted ? '1': '0'}}"
```

how to write the expression correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look closely at [`v-bind` usage and reference](https://vuejs.org/api/built-in-directives.html#v-bind). You'll notice you won't need to use double curly braces here.

Instead, do it like below:

```js
v-bind:data-sorted="sorted ? '1': '0'"
```

In this case if `sorted` is truthy, the value of `data-sorted` will be `'1'` otherwise it will be `'0'`.